# Difference between aruku, arukimasu and arukimasen and such

Tags: verbs

Kinda new to this and i'm confused regarding verb variations such as this.

From what I understand aruku and arukimasu are the same just the latter is more polite while arukimasen is more the opposite like 'I dont want to walk'

Comment: Maybe you can read about conjugation of verbs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjugation and also conjugation of verbs in Japanese https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation. In Japanese the negative of a verb (*run* vs. *not run*) is "built into" the verb by changing its form according to certain rules (compare *can* vs. *cannot = can't* in English).

Answer (score 0):

歩{ある}く (aruku) walk, dictionary form

歩{ある}かない (arukanai) not walk, dictionary form

歩{ある}きます (arukimasu) walk, -masu form

歩{ある}きません (arukimasen) not walk, -masu form

In conversational setting, the -masu verb is indeed the polite form.

To "not like to walk" is actually 歩{ある}きたくない (arukitakunai).

Comment: Bad phrasing, So masen is more the opposite I guess, the negative form.

Comment: @Ereuas `Bad phrasing` -- Could you tell me which part you are referring to?